# How to not duplicate validation?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Let's imagine I have a Service method which creates a customer:

```
public Customer CreateCustomer(string name)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    throw new InvalidCustomerNameException(name);

  _customersRepository.Add(new Customer(name));
}
```

If this code is called from ASP.NET MVC I need to create ASP.NET MVC specific validation (to show to user which fields are filled incorrectly) before calling CreateCustomer. But in this case validation logic is duplicated. Is there any way to get rig of validation duplication?

Comment: Duplicate validation is not always a bad thing... Each layer should validate data according to their own needs and insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) framework.

You need just describe validation rules for certain model.
It's integrative to ASP.NET MVC and may be used directly in code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DataAnnotations](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx). I think in CRUD based app this is all you need. But I personally hate littering my classes with attributes.